# Nothing was returned from render at promise return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a request to API and only after render my page. For this, I used async function and in return method, I used to promise, but I get the error:

```
Nothing was returned from render.

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.data = []
    }

    async getRequest() {
       const response = await fetch({'http://my url'})
       const data = await response.json();
       //exampe
       this.data = data[0]
       return respons
    }

    render() {
        this.getRequest()
            .then((data) => {
               return(
                  <div>
                    {this.data}
                  </div>
               )
            }
     }
}
```

I think the best, is use promise. How fixed? Thanks

Comment: render is NOT, an async method.  So promises will not help you here,.  Like @Mrchief said in his answer, you could do your request in componentDidMount, and then update the state when you get the result.  You could also render something useful like `loading..`, or similar while the request is active.

Comment: Just noticed your SSR, comment, if ssr is promise aware.  Your problem is likely because your not returning your promise.. try -> `return this.getRequest().then(......`

Comment: No, this way is not correct. Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in Main in Container in App in Capture. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot data fetches and promises in your render. You should move all the API calls to `componentDidMount` and render should be just returning the elements.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getRequest()
        .then((data) => { this.setState({ data }) })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
        {this.state.data}
        </div>
    )
}
```

As noted in comments, for SSR, you can try using [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) in place of `componentDidMount`. This will require React v16.3 and above.

Comment: No, I'm need implement  ssr for my site. Render method must be return full date, without api call and update state. Request to my page => Component is call api => and only now is render my page

Comment: For SSR, you can try using `componentWillMount` but it has been deprecated. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html. You're better off fetching the data outside your component and then passing it as props during SSR.

Comment: I is readed getDerivedStateFromProps, but he is impossible is run in async. Exampe:   static async getDerivedStateFromProps() {
    await setTimeout(() => (console.log(1)), 3000)
    await console.log(2)
  } Total: 2,1